# Pandas casting to category still results in different datatypes when plotting with Seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to cast a column to a category as the 2 data sets I am reading in do not have the same datatype for the column I am interested in. They do contain the same set of possible values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

```
df1 = pd.read_csv (r'set1.csv', decimal=",")
df2 = pd.read_csv (r'set2.csv', decimal=",")
print(df1['score'].dtype)
print(df2['score'].dtype)
```

Gives: object & int64. Casting them as so:

```
df1['score'] = df1['score'].astype('category')
df2['score'] = df2['score'].astype('category')
print(df1['score'].dtype)
print(df2['score'].dtype)
```

Gives: category & category. However when I try to plot this using Seaborn I am getting 10 categories for the score column 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I am guessing switching to score does not change the data type as I am expecting and Seaborn still sees 2 different data types.

I concatenate them as so:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort = False, ignore_index = True)
```

Am I correct and how would I fix this?

Comment: Your score column is `integer` so, your problem might solve by converting the score column to `int` by using `.astype(int)` or you can also try to convert your data after concatenating dataframes.

Comment: The fact that a column of numbers is getting read in with an object dtype suggests a problem with the underlying data. For example, your file might have spaces in the numeric fields. This is a problem that needs to be solved upstream of seaborn.

Answer (score 0):

see Initially your `df1['score']` is of type `object(string)` and `df2['score']` is of type `int`

so when you change `df1['score'] = df1['score'].astype('category')` it converts into `category` but initial values in this `category` are of `string` type

and similarly when you change `df2['score'] = df2['score'].astype('category')` it converts into `category` but initial values in this `category` are of `int` type

so basically  if you have some values which are repeated many times in your particular column then they occupy seperate space in memory even if they are repeated so to reduced memory space taken by them unnecessarly we make them as category

so when we make them `category` then the repeated multiple values are referencing to the unique values that are repeated multiple times and due to this they don't occupy seperate space in memory

**Now comes to your solution:-**

Initially :-

```
df1 = pd.read_csv (r'set1.csv', decimal=",")
df2 = pd.read_csv (r'set2.csv', decimal=",")
```

Then:-

```
df1['score'] = df1['score'].astype('int')
```

Now `df1['score']` and `df2['score']` are of type `int`

Now finally change them in category:-

```
df1['score'] = df1['score'].astype('category')
df2['score'] = df2['score'].astype('category')
```

Now plot them